# How to update CombinedCamera parameters in Three.JS?

Tags: parameters, camera, three.js

I am going to change the Near Clipping Plane parameter and then update camera to see the result.

First I create camera with near clipping plane=10 and then I want to set it to 700.
I wrote the following code, but after camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); , it sets to 10 again!!

```
camera = new THREE.CombinedCamera(window.innerWidth ,window.innerHeight ,40 ,10 ,10000 ,-500 ,100); //near clipping plane is defined 10  
camera.position.set( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
camera.near = 700;   //near =700
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();  //near=10 !!!! whyyyyy!!! 
scene.add( camera );
```

Then I used :
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.near=700;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

It resolved!!!

I think there is a bug in "CombinedCamera" when you use camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `CombinedCamera`, what you want to do is this:

```
camera.cameraP.near = 700;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```